# Need solution to avoid repeated scanning in huge table

Tags: sql, sql-server, events, combinations, tagging

I have a event table which has 40 columns and fill up to 2 billion records. In that event table i would like to query for a combination event i.e Event A with Event B. Sometimes I may want to find more combination like Event A with B and C. It may goes to 5 or 6 combination.

I don't want to scan that table for every event in combination i.e Scanning for event A and scanning for event B. And I need a generic approach for more combination scanning as well.

Note: That 2 billion records is partitioned based on event date and data is been equally split.

Eg:

[image: Sample Data]

Need to find id's which has event A,B,C and need to find id's which has only A,B.

This number of combination is dynamic. I don't want to scan that table for each event and finally intersect the result.

Comment: I am learning indexes. I think it is advisable to use non clustered index on event column(as shown in image).

Comment: Find ids that have event A,B,C  all on the same date or just ever? What version of SQL Server?

Comment: both case are applicable. For some combination need to check in same date and for some date check is not required.

Comment: version of SQL Server?

Comment: You said: "event table which has 40 columns" but I only see 3

Comment: Sql server 2012

Comment: For this problem only these 3 columns are enough. That's why i have mentioned only those 3 columns.

Comment: When you are looking for combined event what do you need for it to be an event? Same ID + same date? Same ID? Same date?

Comment: If any of these answers helped you [please consider accepting them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Accepting answers rewards the contributor and helps others to find working answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be some mileage in using a sql server equivalent of the mysql group_concat function.
For example

```
drop table t
create table t (id int, dt date, event varchar(1))
insert into t values
(1,'2017-01-01','a'),(1,'2017-01-01','b'),(1,'2017-01-01','c'),(1,'2017-01-02','c'),(1,'2017-01-03','d'),
(2,'2017-02-01','a'),(2,'2017-02-01','b')

select id,
        stuff(
    (
    select cast(',' as varchar(max)) + t1.event
    from t as t1
    WHERE t1.id  = t.id
    order by t1.id
    for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, '') AS groupconcat
from t
group by t.id

Results in

id          groupconcat
----------- -----------
1           a,b,c,c,d
2           a,b
```

If you then add a patindex

```
select * from
(
select id,
        stuff(
    (
    select cast(',' as varchar(max)) + t1.event
    from t as t1
    WHERE t1.id  = t.id
    order by t1.id
    for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, '') AS groupconcat
from t
group by t.id
) s
where patindex('a,b,c%',groupconcat) > 0
```

you get this

```
id          groupconcat
----------- ------------
1           a,b,c,c,d
```

Comment: I tried this solution. It works as expected. Only concern now I have is performance. Because that event table would have maximum of 2 billion records. Doing Stuff and self join, would run for long. Any suggestion please?

Comment: I would be interested to know how long it does take as a base line.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from table as A
JOIN table AS B
    ON A.Id = B.Id AND A.Date = B.Date
WHERE Date = '1-Jan'
AND A.Event = 'A'
AND B.Event = 'B'
```

This will give you rows, where Date is '1-Jan' and Id is same for both events.
You can join table again and again if you want to filter by more events.

Comment: My combination is dynamic. I may have 5 to 6 combination.. I don't want to do 6 inner join. that would reduce emy performance

Comment: If performance for query is critical, then you can split events into separate columns. Given the fact you have only limited number of events - which i don't know. It will take little bit more space in table, but will give you better performance for queries.

Comment: I may have around 600 distinct events. I can't have a separate table for each event.

Comment: Then I don't see any other option here, than self join I mentioned. Also note that you will have to add join for each event you want excluded from the set. And for performance concerns, the query will select all occurrences of event A on specific date, then do scan over Ids, which will be much faster and of course use indexes. If you add additional join, it will operate on much smaller dataset and will be even faster (the last pass, not whole query). Go and try it. Of course you will need appropriate indexes on the table.

Answer (score 0):

The [having clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql) allows you to filter using the result of an [aggregate function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql).  I've used a regular count but you may need a distinct count, depending on your table design.

Example:

```
-- Returns ids with 3 or more events.
SELECT
    x.Id,
    COUNT(*) AS EventCount
FROM
(
    VALUES
        (1, '2017-01-01', 'A'),
        (1, '2017-01-01', 'B'),
        (1, '2017-01-03', 'C'),
        (1, '2017-01-04', 'C'),
        (1, '2017-01-05', 'E'),
        (2, '2017-01-01', 'A'),
        (2, '2017-01-01', 'B'),
        (3, '2017-01-01', 'A')
) AS x(Id, [Date], [Event])
GROUP BY
    x.Id
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 2
;
```

Returns

```
Id  EventCount
1   5
```

Comment: Gowrl24 - you said that you are looking for solution that is fast and yet, you choose slowest solution. May I ask what is wrong with @destination-data solution? Because according to my tests it was fastest of them. When I run these three queries on my artificial data of couple thousands of records with around 30 distinct events, then execution plan says: 15% for destination-data 20% for my solution with two joins and 65% for P.Salmon. I am just guessing, but it will get even worse when more events are added. Just try it and trust your optimizer. And don't forget indexes.